# Mounting Windows AD share on active directry joined Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: fstab, automount, cifs

Can anyone please advise the best way to permanently mount the Windows share on an AD connected Ubuntu. As the user is logging onto Ubuntu with his/her Active directory account that has access to the share that I want to mount, but when try to mount the drive using fstab and mount.cifs command, it prompting for credentials. So I am able to mount the drive, If I provide or save the credentials. However, the goal is to mount it at the user level without saving the credentials or having user to provide his Active Directory credentials again for mounting. I have joined the Ubuntu to active directory, in hope that the active directory users can log on to Ubuntu and access the network shares that they have access without reentering their AD credentials.
Your help will be greatly appreciated,

Parmod

Comment: Thanks Karel, I can mount the drive, If I provide or save the credentials. However, the goal is to mount it at user level with the credentials that the user is logging on with so that the user doesn't have to provide or save the credentials. I have joined the Ubuntu to active directory, in hope that the active directory users can log on to Ubuntu and access the network shares that they have access to.

Comment: Please edit the question and include new information from your comment.